# how to detect if if a specific string in another groovy file has been modified

Tags: groovy, smartthings

this is part of the groovy file that I wanted to detect if the description field has been changed

```
/**
 *  Copyright 2015 SmartThings
 *
 *  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
 *  in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
 *
 *  Alfred Workflow
 *
 *  Author: SmartThings
 */

definition(
    name: "Alfred Workflow",
    namespace: "vlaminck",
    author: "SmartThings",
    description: "This SmartApp allows you to interact with the things in your physical graph through Alfred.",
    category: "Convenience",
```

Any help

thanks a lot

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.